# TSQL - Conditionally "Cross Join" Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Code (staging sample data):

```
DECLARE @LookupTab TABLE
    (
        [Val] INT NOT NULL
    ) ;
INSERT INTO @LookupTab
VALUES
    ( 111 ) -- Option 1
  , ( 112 ) -- Option 2
;

DECLARE @DataTab TABLE
    (
        [Id]    INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
      , [Val]   INT NOT NULL
      , [Extra] VARCHAR(10)
    ) ;
INSERT INTO @DataTab
VALUES
    ( 111, 'One' )  -- Option 1
  , ( 111, 'One' )  -- Option 1
  , ( 112, 'Two' )  -- Option 2
  , ( 223, 'Both' ) -- Option 1 & 2
  , ( 223, 'Both' ) -- Option 1 & 2
;
```

Detail:
@LookupTab is basically a filter that will have either 0, 1, or both values (111 - Option 1 and 112 - Option 2).
@DataTab is the actual data in the table (can be huge). The Val field in this table can either be 111 (Option 1), 112 (Option 2), or 223 (Both Options).

Expectations:

> If @LookupTab only passes in 111, I want Id's 1,2,4,5 returned (total
>   4 rows). Like so

```
Id  Val Extra
1   111 One
2   111 One
4   111 Both
5   111 Both
```

> If @LookupTab only passes in 112, I want Id's 3,4,5 returned (total 3
>   rows)

```
Id  Val Extra
3   112 Two
4   112 Both
5   112 Both
```

> If @LookupTab passes in 111 and 112, I want Id's 1,2,3,4,5 returned,
>   but since Id 4 and 5 are "Both Options", I want two rows returned for
>   each. Like so

```
Id  Val Extra
1   111 One
2   111 One
3   112 Two
4   111 Both
4   112 Both
5   111 Both
5   112 Both
```

My unsuccessful try:

```
SELECT      [T1].[Id]
          , [T2].[Val]
          , [T1].[Extra]
FROM        @DataTab AS [T1]
CROSS JOIN  @LookupTab AS [T2]
--WHERE       [T1].[Val] = [T2].[Val] ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT      [T1].[Id]
          , [T2].[Val]
          , [T1].[Extra]
FROM        @DataTab AS [T1]
INER JOIN   @LookupTab AS [T2]
ON          [T2].[Val] = [T1].[Val] OR [T1].[Val] = 223
ORDER BY    [T1].[Id]
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1097f0c74083d1fe0ab7ee590bb8cc26).

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution. Seeing it makes sense, thinking about it before seeing didn't, if it makes any sense. haha Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are dealing with a large amount of data, I would be careful about about `or` in the `from` clause.  I would recommend `union all` instead:

```
select d.id, v.val, d.extra
from  @DataTab d join
      @LookupTab l
      on l.val = d.val
union all
select d.id, v.val, d.extra
from  @DataTab d join
      @LookupTab l
      on l.val = 223;
```

The `or` (as suggested by forpas) might not make a difference performance-wise in this case.  As a general rule, though, I find that it hurts performance.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for an alternative and a warning. Unfortunately, my real query has a lot of joins that builds up to @DataTab (simplified it for this question), Going to test out the other solution and keep an eye out for performance issues. Thank you and Cheers!